# Spring Boot findById is not working but findAllById works fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an Bid entity defined as follows

```
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "bid_details")
public class Bid {

    private enum STATUS { INITIATED, DRAFT, COMPLETED }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "govt_bid_id", nullable = false)
    private String govtBidNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "release_date", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date releaseDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private User createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private User updatedBy;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private STATUS status;

    @Column(name = "avg_turnover")
    private String avgTurnover;

    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "docs_required", columnDefinition = "json")
    private List<String> docsRequired;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
   private STATUS status;

}
```

and the corresponding columns are present in the `bid_details` tables. I have bid repository defined as follows:

```
public interface BidRepository extends JpaRepository<Bid, Integer> {
}
```

now when I try to access data by id using `findById` it is throwing `No Value Present` exception whereas if I try to access the data using `findAllById` I am getting correct result. Not able to figure out what's causing this weird behaviour.

Also, if I execute `findAll` first and then `findById` it is giving the correct result.

I am using spring-boot version 2.1.1

following is code where the entity is saved in the db

```
public Bid addBid(BidRequest bidRequest) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(bidRequest.getCreatedBy()).get();
        Bid bid = new Bid();
        modelMapper.map(bidRequest, bid);
        bid.setCreatedBy(user);
        return bidRepository.save(bid);
    }
```

BidRequest class is as follows:

```
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class BidRequest {

    private String govtBidNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date releaseDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endDate;

    private int createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdDate;

    private int updatedBy;

    private String status;

    private List<String> docsRequired;

}
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the JPA 1st level cache. Can you show the code that creates the entity in the database? Is that in the same transaction as the attempt to read it?

Comment: Where are the transaction boundaries? Especially with respect to the `find*` calls?

Comment: What are transaction boundaries ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction typically in the form of https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: Why are you passing bidRequest.getCreatedBy to the userRepository.findById call? You are passing a User object when it is expecting an Integer id.

Comment: Also if you could provide the BidRequest Enitity and Repository it would help troubleshoot.

Comment: @JamesGawron added the BidRequest class

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `orElse` like this

```
findById(id).orElse(null);
```

Because `findById` returns an `Optional` object so you have to write `orElse()` after `findById()`

Comment: Yes you can throw an error in `orElse`. Actually, it is suggested that you do so.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it does not fix this issue

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure out the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After turning on sql logs I found that  Hibernate produced several inner joins for findById command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).